# Is it possible to observe the residue?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was wondering if there is a way to recognise the value (or at least to say if it is non zero) just by observing the plot of a complex function? for instance, looking at (x,y,real(f)) or (x,y,im(f) ).

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $f(z)=\frac1{z^2}$ and $g(z)=\frac1{z^2}+\frac1z$. Then $\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)=0$ and $\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\bigl(g(z)\bigr)=1$. However, the graphs that you mentioned look the same with respect to both functions.

Comment: So  is there a way to interpret the residue?

Comment: Sure there is. The residue at $a$ being non zere is equivalent to the assertion that $f$ has no primitive near $a$.

Comment: Equivalent? Having a primitive Isn't equivalent to f being equal to the taylor expansion?

Comment: If you are talking about residues, you are talking about singularities. Therefore, there is no Taylor expansion. The function $\frac1z$ has no Taylor expansion centered at $0$.

Comment: I do agree, but your argument does not apply for 1/z^2 for example. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: But $\frac1{z^2}$ has residue $0$ and it *has* a primitive: $-\frac1z$.

Comment: Oh... Okay you re right... I need to think about it... Thank you